# python format file contents to send vial html mail

Tags: python, html, email

I'm using python to send the contents of a file to an email using this approach:

```
f = open(file,"r")
contents = f.read()
```

Inside the html code I put:

```
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <h1>Alerta</h1>
        <p>{contents}</p>
        </body>
        </html>
                    """.format(contents=contents)
```

The file looks like this:

```
phrase 1
phrase 2
phrase 3
phrase 4
```

But in the email i got:

```
phrase 1 phrase 2 phrase 3 phrase 4
```

Is there a way to get the email in a similar way to the original file?

Comment: Use `<pre>` instead of `<p>` or replace line breaks with `<br>` tags in `contents`.

Comment: Hi  @Selcuk, the <pre> tag worked! Thanks.